# Linking up a project

Tags: java, css, eclipse, netbeans, notepad++

How can I arrange project files and linking them together?

For example, I love programming [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) in [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29), but I would rather do the Java part in [NetBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans).

Is there a good way to combine these files somehow into one project, different scripts written in different [IDEs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) and link them up so they run together, that is, a website?
Or better still, an all-in-one IDE that has great compatibility with all or most languages and language/GUI plug in facilities.

(I'm a hobbyist programmer.)

Comment: [visual studio 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) is good. But I doubt using java on it.

Answer (score 1):

NetBeans is ideal for this.  A single project can have any number of classes that declare a `main()` method, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211566/creating-jars-with-multiple-main-classes-in-netbeans/2211980#2211980) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127546/choosing-a-java-ide-for-homework-assignments/2127928#2127928). You can hook into the build script, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955299/netbeans-adding-resource-files-to-jar-file-with-ant).

[image]

Comment: Netbeans also allows multiple "source" locations, so you "need" to keep all the files in the same location (although it usually easier)

Answer (score 1):

You can continue using [NetBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) to manage your project. Copy the CSS files into your project, but you can still keep editing the files using the Notepad++ if you prefer. You can build and deploy your project from NetBeans.

Basically, use NetBeans as your project container, but use whatever you like to edit the files. You will probably need to refresh the project from NetBeans to pick up the latest changes.

I am not so familiar with NetBeans, but I know that the [Eclipse IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) has plugins for many different types of development. It might be suitable as a single IDE for all your development needs.

Comment: One can search for CSS related plugins [here](http://plugins.netbeans.org/). I use a different external HTML editor on Mac OS, and each sees the others changes.

Comment: you can just edit the file in Notepad++ and Netbeans will pick up the changes without the need to refresh